# Hosting multiple sites in IIS 6, one need SSL

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-6

We've got a Windows Server 2003 running IIS 6 where we host multiple sites with different domains. www.site1.com, www.site2.com etc.

Now one of these sites need a SSL certificate, so I ordered a certificate from rapidssl.com for the domain www.site1.com.

The problem:
After installing this SSL certificate all https request to this server, regardless of domain, gets redirected to the www.site1.com site.
FYI: This is the only site on the server that got a SSL certificate installed.

Anyone?

Comment: Are all sites using the same IP?

Comment: Yes, they all use the same IP. Seperated by host headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set /w3svc//SecureBindings ":443:" solved the problem.

Comment: can you explain in a bit more detail. the script you added here doesn't seem to reference any specific domain? We're having similar issues and are about to embark on the wildcard SSL approach, but want to get as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](http://www.digicert.com/faq-installing.htm#uniqueip), SSL does not support host headers. If you have more than one IP on your server, try using one IP for the SSL website and use other IPs for the other sites. If you don't, ask for another IP for your server to your helpdesk.

Comment: According to http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/596b9108-b1a7-494d-885d-f8941b07554c.mspx?mfr=true it is possible, but I don't see how this will prevent the other sites from using the SSL 'default website' for https requests. Then again: I haven't tried this yet. Any big risks involved in execute the command: cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set /w3svc/<site identifier>/SecureBindings ":443:<host header>" ?

Comment: Well I think you found your answer. As for the risks... If you have a backup server you can switch to while you try the command, do switch! I guess you can remove the site from IIS and create it back again in case of problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible...

http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-configure-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-6.html

http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/configure-iis-host-headers.htm

As per post by Kulvis