# Multiple sites with wildcard SSL on IIS 6

Tags: iis-6, windows-server-2003

We have a server running **Win Server 2003 SP1** with **IIS 6**. The server runs **three websites** of which only **one needs to be secured**. However, adding HTTPS in front of any of the others redirects the user to the secured website.

From my reading I can see it's because pre SP1 SSL worked based on IP addresses only whereas post SP1 it is possible to configure it for host headers using some scripts. That's all great.

What I need to know is what the final requirements be if I have the following for my applications:

1. http://www.site1.com - SSL not required, but if the user types in https://www.site1.com it should not redirect to https://app.site1.com
2. http://www.site2.com - SSL not required, same as 1.
3. http://app.site1.com - SSL required.

### Questions

1. Do I need to purchase 2 wildcard certificates for this configuration. One for *.site1.com and one for *.site2.com?
2. If I do get two wildcard certificates do I configure each of the sites to use them and assume that the user can choose to view https://www.site1.com can do so without being redirected

There are a number of similar questions on Stack, but not quite the same requirements. See
[Hosting multiple sites in IIS 6, one need SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976084/hosting-multiple-sites-in-iis-6-one-need-ssl)

---

### Edit

**Microsoft's Recommendation on IIS6 and Wildcard certificates**
I found a link where Microsoft explains more about using Wildcard certificates to configure the scenario I have described: https://web.archive.org/web/20161114165638/https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/596b9108-b1a7-494d-885d-f8941b07554c.mspx?mfr=true
**Note:** We are definitely having the scenario where if the user browses to https://www.site1.com the browser displays the exception (which is correct) but then after accepting the exception they're being redirected to https://app.site1.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to secure only http://app.site1.com then you don’t need to buy wildcard ssl certificate. You can simply secure your website using domain SSL Certificate. (Recommended SSL: RapidSSL Certificate, Thawte SSL123, QuickSSL Premium)

Suppose your all three websites are hosted on same IP address.

When user type https://www.site1.com then he will not redirect to your https://app.site1.com but visitor will get domain mismatch error in his browser because of same IP address.

Wildcard SSL can only secure your primary domain plus unlimited sub domain for that primary domain name.

Example: site1.com, www.site1.com, mail.site1.com, blog.site1.com

If you want to secure *site1.com and *.site2.com then you should go with Multi Domain SSL Certificate instead of Wildcard ssl certificate.

Comment: Hi @sophie. We certainly get the mismatch error on the browser, but when the user adds the exception they're being redirected to https://app.site1.com. The reason I mention wildcard certificates is because Microsoft talks only about wildcard certs. See the following link: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/596b9108-b1a7-494d-885d-f8941b07554c.mspx?mfr=true